# The specified element mode is not supported on element: "ul"

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

when i tried to edit manually added unordered list getting this error in console "The specified element mode is not supported on element: "ul"

**ckeditor version is 4.10.1**

Comment: could you please explain with code examples

Comment: @mariappank its simple , editing an ul tag with inline ck editor.
e.g 
<ul>
<li> item one</li>
</ul>
This html will through above error